# Using Difference in Difference (DiD) to measure the impact of austerity measures?

Tags: difference-in-difference, social-science, politics

I am trying to see if there is any causal relationship between the rise in vote share of France's leading extreme right-wing party *Le Front National* and the rate at which austerity measures took place after 2008.

Austerity measures started after 2008, therefore I have three 'waves' I could assess: the 2002, 2007, 2012 presidential elections. My logic is that I would be able to see if there was a significant increase in vote share for the National Front in the wake of impending austerity measures, as opposed to previous years during which public spending was untouched.

Of course there are control variables and etc, I am just wondering if my logic thus far is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The diff-in-diff estimator is reliant on a *control group* to which the treatment group is being compared. You do not have such a control group.

What you might ask is rather: was there a [structural break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_break) in the support for FN when austerity measures were implemented? Time-series on the support - for example, from public opinion polls - might give you an insight into this. Another might be the number of unique visitors on the FN webpage.